# How would you call a variety that is locally a complete intersection up to defect c?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, terminology, singularity-theory

Let $X$ be an equidimensional variety of dimension $n$ over a field that can be covered by open subvarieties of certain intersections of $N-n$ hypersurfaces in $P^N$ (for a large enough $N$; we consider set-theoretic intersections). Then $X$ can be called locally a set-theoretic complete intersection; this term sounds poorly and does not seem to be standard.

Is there a better term? How would you call $X$ if it is locally an intersection of $N-n+c$ hypersurfaces in $P^N$?

Upd. What do you think about "(locally?) requires only $c$ extra equations"?

Comment: Personally, I would say "set-theoretically local complete intersection."  Since people abbreviate "local complete intersection" as "LCI", you  might abbreviate this as "stLCI".

Comment: Why not "STLCI"?:) Previously I wrote "LSTCI" instead. Was any abbreviation of this sort used in literature?

Comment: I haven't seen a name for it either.